# impediment-y what's the meaning of this

Tags: meaning, neologisms

The sentence I'm trying to figure out is:

> Unfortunately, the distance, etc are impediment-y enough for me

Is it a typo or a neologism?

**Edit:** a little bit more of context:

> Unfortunately, the distance, etc are impediment-y enough for me **[to continue/have/consider this relationship]**

Comment: More info, a context, is necessary. Unless this is common technical jargon (gads what an oxymoron), we won't know an 'impediment-y' from a 'hurdle-z' or a 'whatsawhosit-w'

Comment: It looks like an adjectivization of *"impediment"*. Probably not in the dictionaries, but quite comprehensible.

Comment: @PeterShor - interesting ... I read it like a math / physics term.  So you think it means something like 'the distance is enough to impede me' ?

Comment: @Howard: that's it.

Comment: @PeterShor - we need a faq along the lines of "How not to do it: poorly styled English,"  or maybe just "EngFish" :))

Comment: It'd been a little easier to understand without the hyphenated y - though still clunky! :-)

Comment: I have added more context. The writer is an well educated Ivy-league graduate if this helps.

Comment: @HowardPautz I agree. But make it all English-y and stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The person who wrote this should have written: "Unfortunately the distance is too much of an impediment for me [to continue this relationship]."

I'm guessing it's intentionally ungrammatical to make it sound informal and spur of the moment, as opposed to carefully premeditated. Proper usage here comes off cold and informal.

Answer (score 0):

Might be physics or maths terminology.

Generally, If we plot a graph of distance vs. time, then while labeling the axes. 
**Distance is measured on the **y-**axis.** (Northward)

Time is graphed on the X-axis, because time does not depend on distance, however, the "distance covered does depend on the time taken".

=> Can we think it means 'the distance is too overwhelming' ?

Comment: The meaning is right, but the interpretation is wrong --nothing to do with math or graphs.

Comment: I'm not so sure it has nothing to do with math